# RubyMine: "Expression can be simplified" But how?

Tags: ruby, rubymine

How to simplify this expression?

```
m.immutable = params[:immutable] || false
```

RubyMine suggests: "Expression can be simplified. This inspection warns about redundant parts inside boolean function", but doesn't say what to do.

The idea is to assign false if "immutable" parameter wasn't passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just click Alt+Enter and RubyMine will show

```
m.immutable = params[:immutable]
```

In some cases this can help you, but if you are not passing param then immutable will be nil,
which could be not what your expecting

Comment: "immutable will be nil, which could be not what your expecting", yes, that am I talking about. But RubyMine knows better...

Comment: @Paul, in that case RubyMine is wrong then. The two statements aren't equivalent.

Comment: Yeah, RubyMine might be being a little aggressive here. `nil` evaluates to `false` in a boolean context, but they're not the same when compared with `==`.

Comment: In response to the question itself, in case anyone else gets here because of `nil` vs `false`: it's worth asking yourself _why_ you want to explicitly have a `false` when you could just use whatever the falsey value happens to be in `params[:immutable]`

Answer (score 1):

This is a better way to achieve this:

```
m.immutable = !! params[:immutable]
```

Using `!!` is a Ruby trick to make sure an expression is converted to boolean.
e.g. even if `params[:immutable]` evaluates to `nil`, the `!!` will convert it to `false` -- other wise it will be `true`

Comment: The style guide associated with RuboCop says to [avoid the use of `!!`](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#no-bang-bang). Since `nil` is falsey anyway, it's unnecessary.

Comment: Sure, RuboCop is very opinionated, but that does not mean it ialways correct in it's rules or assessments.

IMHO it is very important to consciously select which RuboCop rules to enable

I found some of the rules pretty awkward - some even pretty annoying (changing around logic, loops, and replacing select/reject, etc...)

There are valid scenarios where the difference between nil and false is important, and there are cases where you want to emphasize that a value is boolean. If you want boolean `!!` is the Ruby way to achieve it. This way you can distinguish between not-set, true, false

Comment: Definitely -- and if `m.immutable` is supposed to always be a boolean I like your answer best, since it makes that immediately clear -- from OP's code I had assumed that it was supposed to be either false or some value.